Log4j2 RollingFile configuration is not working with efs ( elastic file system ) for SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy policy
I'm trying to implement the RollingFile policy, but rolling is not executed even though the log file size is more than 50MB. The log files are on efs.
The current version of Log4j is 2.17.1.
<RollingFile name="FileServerMessages" fileName="%<INTERFACE_LOG>%/%<INTERFACE_ID>%/serverMessage.log"
                     filePattern="%<INTERFACE_LOG>%/%<INTERFACE_ID>%/serverMessage.log%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.zip">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT}{UTC} %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="7"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax" compressionLevel="9" max="14"/>
        </RollingFile>

